# Setting a Variable "as" a Class

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderCell
```

You can see the code above. I just wanted to ask that how and why we can, or should, set a tableViewCell as a Class? In this case it is CustomHeaderCell. For further info about the code here's the thing: I am just creating a custom header by following a guide I saw in web.

Comment: "You can see the code above." Actually, no, we can't very well when you paste in screenshots of Xcode.

Comment: I can write down the code but can you tell me, It doesn't show up, or too small to see?

Comment: All this hatred...I don't get the point. @rickster

Comment: @LinusG. Not a big deal man. Let's focus on the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this pattern when (a) you know the actual class of the object being returned, whereas the compiler can't reasonably know this; and (b) you need to then use the methods/properties of this subclass.

In this case, you probably have a cell prototype in your storyboard that specifies a `CustomHeaderCell` base class (or you have registered a class or NIB such that you know that the `HeaderCell` identifier will return a `CustomHeaderCell` instance). Furthermore, you presumably want to reference the properties of this `CustomHeaderCell` (e.g. setting the `text` property of its custom `UILabel` outlets or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for answer! But the thing I mean is not that to be simple you cannot make an apple as a banana. If I am not wrong, views and classes are not same. This is the point I am stuck

Comment: No, of course not. In this case, it's not so much apple vs banana as it is apple vs Granny Smith apple (i.e. a particular type of apple). Your `CustomHeaderCell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. The cast doesn't "make" it a `CustomHeaderCell`, but rather through the cell prototype (or whatever), you happen to know it really is a `CustomHeaderCell` and we simply want to tell the compiler that this is the case.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very very very much, Rob! I think we can say it is like Apple vs Macintosh Apple, if you know what I mean :P.